# Getting R printed texts to have color esp. in R markdown knits?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, rnotebook

Very simple question: I love writing R notebooks/markdowns, and with something like `highlight: tango` I can give background color to codes when I knit my notebook to pdfs.

However, I don't know how to give colored backgrounds or colored fonts to printed outputs in R. For example, suppose I have the following chunk.

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
writeLines("Help")
```
````

I'd like to see the word Help to be highlighted, say in red font with gray background. How can I achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For PDF output, below are some `latex` commands to get colored text and shading. (For additional shading options, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59342/4762) at the Tex Stack Exchange site.) However, I'm not sure how to get the output from `writeLines` shaded. Enclosing the code chunk in a `\shaded` environment causes an error. Hopefully someone will come along with a solution that works with code chunk output.

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
  - \usepackage{framed}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!10}

\color{red}

```{r}
writeLines("help")
```

\begin{shaded}

Red text with a gray background.

\end{shaded}

Red text.

\color{black}

Black text.

\colorlet{shadecolor}{red!10} 

\begin{shaded}

Black text with a red background.

\end{shaded}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{red!90} 

\begin{shaded}

Black text with a darker red background.

\end{shaded}
````

And here's the resulting PDF document:

[image]

Comment: Ah, just one additional question---is there a way to put a background to the printed "## help" part as well? The technique doesn't seem to work when you move the ```\begin{shaded}``` right below ```writeLines("help")``` to above it.

Comment: Yes, I noted in my answer that I'm not sure how to print chunk output with a background, because enclosing the code chunk in a `\shaded` environment causes an error. I'm working on this and will come back with a solution if I find one.

Comment: Ooh, I missed that in my excitement. Excuse me. But thanks again for the current solution---I can work the other way around and shade texts while leaving prints, because all I wished to do was clearly show blocks of code prints and blocks of texts apart.

Answer (score 11):

with `kableExtra`, you can format your texts in R using `text_spec`

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
options(knitr.table.format = "latex")
```

`r text_spec("Help", color = "red")`

`r text_spec("Help Help", background = "#D05A6E", color = "white", bold = T)`

`r text_spec("Hello", font_size = 20)`

`r text_spec("World", angle = 180)`
````

You get
[image]

Same goes for HTML
[image]

See more in the **Cell/Text Specification** of the package [vignette](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/).

Answer (score 1):

For a way within R, my `huxtable` package lets you set background and text colour for tables. I don't know of any within-R package that does it for plain text (maybe `crayon`?)

```
library(huxtable)
ht <- hux(c("Red", "Blue"), c("White bg", "Black bg"))
text_color(ht)[, 1] <- c("red", "blue")
background_color(ht)[, 2] <- c("white", "black")
to_latex(ht) # or just print within a rmarkdown document
```