# If else in R Markdown, colored text

Tags: r, colors, formatting, markdown

I have a R Markdown child-file, which should produce different output based on a R-condition .

My code (sorry it is not reproducible):

```
{r results='asis', echo = FALSE}
if (class(robject) == "character") {
  cat("**R object is empty!**")  # This text should appear in RED in the Output (HTML) file.
} else {
  cat("### Data columns\n")
  cat("\n")
  kable(robject)
  cat("\n")
}
```

What the code does:

If my `robject` is not a `data.frame` it is set to an empty string (`robject <- ""`). With this "trick" it is possible to `if_else` about `robject`.

In my R Markdown file it should be printed either "R object is empty!" or a summary of the dataset (which is a `data.frame` again). If the dataset is empty, the text should appear in RED!

Two questions:

1. How to print the text in RED (or every other color) using the `cat` command as in the example above?
   ([I tried `text_spec` from `kableextra` as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298106/getting-r-printed-texts-to-have-color-esp-in-r-markdown-knits), [I tried `crayron`-Package as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145079/r-how-to-output-a-partially-colored-string-in-r) and [I tried to enter html_tags with `print/cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819258/format-text-inside-r-code-chunk) . Neither worked!)
2. Maybe it is better to if else outside the R Chunk. Unfortunately this approach did not work either [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46686678/5148239)

Thank you for any help.

If you need some further information, please ask me for it. Thanks!

Comment: What matters here is the way you will then view your markdown file, if it is in md syntax highlighting or as html output. If html, then you can go for html styling of red text. What exactly is the question - how to style in html or how to embed it in if-else?

Answer (score 0):

For HTML you can wrap the text in `<span>` and use CSS to set the color.  If you need to do this more than a couple of times, you can wrap it up in a simple function.

````
```{r results='asis', echo = FALSE}

cat_color <- function(message, color = "black") cat(sprintf("<span style = \"color: %s;\">%s</span>\n\n", color, message))

robject <- "some text"

if (class(robject) == "character") {
  cat_color("**R object is empty!**" , "red")  # This text should appear in RED in the Output (HTML) file.
} else {
  cat("### Data columns\n")
  cat("\n")
  kable(robject)
  cat("\n")
}
```
````

[image]